# Object initializes despite wrong values to constructor?

Tags: java, generics, constructor, arguments, javafx

```
Timeline pongAnimation = TimelineBuilder.create()
    .keyFrames(
      new KeyFrame(
        new Duration(10.0),
        new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
          public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent t) {
            checkForCollision();
            int horzPixels = movingRight ? 1 : -1;
            int vertPixels = movingDown ? 1 : -1;
            centerX.setValue(centerX.getValue() + horzPixels);
            centerY.setValue(centerY.getValue() + vertPixels);
          }
        }
      )
    )
    .cycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE)
    .build();
```

This is the JavaFX code from the book that I am reading. It is creating a `KeyFrame` by passing it a `Duration` and an `EventListener`-- no more, no less.

All the constructors for `Timeline` class that are associated with the `EventHandler` need `KeyValues` as argument. However, that is not the case in the code above. The code compiles and even gives the desired output.

**Why?**

Docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html

Comment: Whether this code does what you expect it to depends on what's in the `TimelineBuilder` class.  You need to look at that class to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor you are using is

```
public KeyFrame(Duration time,
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> onFinished,
        KeyValue... values)
```

The parameter `KeyValue...` is a **varargs parameter**. If you don't pass any arguments to the method, it'll be an empty array.

Comment: So, I do not even need to specify that I am passing a `null` or whatever ?

Comment: @LittleChild If you call it like you are, `values` will be a `new KeyValue[0]`. If you instead pass `null` as the third argument in your constructor call, the constructor will receive `new KeyValue[] {null}`.